# mysql to codeigniter active record help

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Active record is a neet concept but sometimes I find it difficult to get more complicated queries to work.  I find this is at least one place the CI docs are lacking.

Anyway,
This is the sql I wrote.  It returns the expected results of quests not yet completed by the user that are unlocked and within the users level requirements:

```
SELECT writing_quests . * 
FROM  `writing_quests` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_quests_completed ON members_quests_completed.quest_id = writing_quests.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN members ON members.id = $user_id
WHERE writing_quests.unlocked =1
AND writing_quests.level_required <= $userlevel
AND members_quests_completed.user_id IS NULL
```

This is the codeigniter active record query, it returns all quests that are unlocked and within the users level requirement:

```
$this->db->select('writing_quests.*');
$this->db->from('writing_quests');
$this->db->join('members_quests_completed', 'members_quests_completed.quest_id = writing_quests.id', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('members', "members.id = $user_id", 'left outer');
$this->db->where('writing_quests.unlock', 1);
$this->db->where('writing_quests.level_required <=', $userlevel);   
$this->db->where('members_quests_completed.user_id is null', null, true);
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the way I am asking for Nulls.  To be thorough, I figured I'd include everything.

Comment: what do you mean there is something wrong?

Comment: The queries return different results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that sometimes CI active record can overcomplicate things. Try this for your IS NULL where clause:

```
$this->db->where('members_quests_completed.user_id IS ','NULL',false);
```

Try also to enable the profiler or echo the generated query with:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

That might shed some light on what the issue is.

Comment: Because he specifically stated that he suspected the issue was with the IS NULL clause - I've used the above syntax, although not his, and that has always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work either.  I'm getting an error:   Unknown column '10' in 'on clause'

'10' is the value of $user_id.  This query works fine if written in sql.  Which is what I might end up doing anyway, this way I can get the userlevel in the sql query rather then passing it in.

Comment: It's your members join line - CI is adding backticks to the table / field names, and it's not intelligent enough to realise your $user_id value isn't a table / field name. You might be able to restructure your query to get the data another way - or, as you say, it might be easier to just call $this->db->query() and be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes CI makes it a bit complicated... you can always use $this->db->query("your very long query") to simplify a bit (if I recall correctly strings are still escaped - not sure). It's a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('column IS NOT NULL')
```

in your case

```
$this->db->where('members_quests_completed.user_id is not null');
```